# Kubuntu 20.04 is not booting up

Tags: boot, 20.04, kubuntu

I have been using Ubuntu for a long time and recently thought of giving Kubuntu 20.04 a try. After a complete installation of the Kubuntu 20.04 it asked for restart of the system. I have restarted it and removed the installation media but it won't boot up.
I shut down the system and tried doing it again but same issue.

I have tried use all disk and manual partitioning of the system and done a fresh install, But the issue is same.

After that I have installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 on same machine and it is working fine.
I have created flash of Both ISO from a windows system using Rufus.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check `/var/log/boot.log`, `/var/log/kern.log` or `/var/log/syslog` for crashes or process it hangs on.

I had a similar issue caused by crashing `sddm` (it wasn't loading GUI) with a certain combination of **linux kernel** and **nvidia driver** and got it fixed after one of the recent updates.